# Disable click on markers in embedded Google map

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have an embedded Google map which has its CSS `top` position adjusted to hide the top bar, since it can't be disabled through the API (at least I wasn't able to find any reference to this). The problem is that by offsetting the map, clicking the map marker hides the "back to map" button, so you can't get back to the map. Is it possible to disable clicking on the markers to bypass this issue?

The original map: https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/viewer?mid=z5HTkcVjHLGw.k95PWTPXBYQ8

The iframe:

```
<iframe src="//www.google.com/maps/d/embed?mid=z5HTkcVjHLGw.k95PWTPXBYQ8&amp;z=6" width="300" height="240"></iframe>
```

Demo https://jsfiddle.net/91123ao1/1/

Comment: What you are trying to do seems to be against Google Maps' permissions: " _While we encourage annotations, you must not significantly alter how Google Maps, Google Earth or Street View would look online. For example, you're not allowed to make any changes to the colors of the product interface or alter how imagery appears (such as adding clouds or other natural elements, blurring, etc.)._ " from https://www.google.com/permissions/geoguidelines.html

Comment: If you still want to really do it, do you need to preserve zooming capabilities on the mini-map?

Comment: You mean by throwing an overlay over the map? That would disable moving around too. I have to consult this with the project manager :)

Comment: Yes, I was thinking that. I tried `document.getElementById('offset').contentWindow.click = function(a) { console.log(a);}` in your fiddle, but it throws a security error: *VM352:59 Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "https://fiddle.jshell.net" from accessing a frame with origin "https://www.google.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.*

Comment: Thanks for the ideas, I'll poke around some more

Answer (score 1):

Well, the only way to do that (that I know of) is to edit the actual HTML of Google Maps, which is highly illegal, because of copyright issues. So, you could just add a `<button>` below the iframe, like so:

```
<div id = "map">
    <iframe src="//www.google.com/maps/d/embed?mid=z5HTkcVjHLGw.k95PWTPXBYQ8&amp;z=6" width="300" height="240"></iframe>
</div>
<br>
<button onclick = "backToMap()">Back to map</button>
```

For the HTML side, and

```
function backToMap() {
    window.location = "https://jsfiddle.net/91123ao1/1/#map"
}
```

For the JavaScript side. I think that'll work, but it might not.